# Cannot call class as a function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple stream to publish on PubNub and later consume.  I can successfully utilize separate functions which log the output to the console or even create a .json file using the `.pipe(new function())`.  However for some reason with this function I am getting the Cannot call a class function.  I have not changed the syntax of the function call at the end of the code, so I am assuming it is something in the PubNubStreamOut() function itself.

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
>       at _classCallCheck (D:\pasco\node_modules\pubnub\lib\node\index.js:27:99)
>       at _class (D:\pasco\node_modules\pubnub\lib\node\index.js:37:5)
>       at new PubNubOutStream (D:\pasco\pubnub.js:24:13)
>       at Object. (D:\pasco\pubnub.js:54:42)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)

The .js file follows:

```
var pubnub = require('pubnub');
var util = require('util');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var Writable = require('stream').Writable;
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var pncfg = {
   ssl           : true,  //  enable TLS Tunneling over TCP
   publish_key   : "PUB_KEY",
   subscribe_key : "SUB_KEY"
};

var twcfg = {
    consumer_key:"...",
    consumer_secret:"...",
    access_token_key:"...",
    access_token_secret:"..."
}



function PubNubOutStream(cfg, channel) {
   Writable.call(this,{objectMode:true});
   var pn = pubnub(cfg);

   this._write = function(obj, encoding, callback) {
       pn.publish({
           channel: channel,
           message: obj,
           callback: () => callback()
       });
   };
}
util.inherits(PubNubOutStream, Writable);

function TwitterStream(cfg, query) {
    Readable.call(this,{objectMode:true});

    var client = new Twitter(cfg);

    this._read = function() { /* do nothing */ };
    var self = this;
    function connect() {
        client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: query},
            function(stream) {
               stream.on('data', (tweet) => self.push(tweet));
               stream.on('error', (error) => connect());
            });
    }
    connect();
 }
 util.inherits(TwitterStream, Readable);

new TwitterStream(twcfg,"#twitter").pipe(new PubNubOutStream(pncfg,"awesome-tweets"));
```

I am not sure why I am getting the class as a function error since I am using the `new PubNubOutStream()`

Comment: Have you tried defining `PubNubOutStream` as a class instead of as a function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I think the problem may be `Writable.call(this,{objectMode:true});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PubNub's [documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk), you should use the following syntax to create a new instance:

```
var PubNub = require('pubnub');
var pn = new PubNub({
    publishKey : 'demo',
    subscribeKey : 'demo'
});
```

The error is due to the fact, that you are calling the PubNub constructor as a function:

```
var pn = pubnub(cfg);
```

And the error message just confirms that:

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function at _classCallCheck

Hope this will put you back on track.